# Generating order number to use instead of ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a column in more Orders table for an order number.

I am wondering what the best course of creating this number is.

I have created the following code in my orders model:

```
before_validation :generate_order_number, on: :create

def generate_order_number
    begin
      self.order_number = SecureRandom.random_number(10*10000)
    end while self.class.find_by(order_number: order_number)
  end
```

This is most likely good but i am wondering if there is a better / more efficient way?

The way the code is, it's always at least a 5 digit randomized number or 6 digit.

Being picky, I would like to have it set at `n` digits.

To clarify, there be be validations on the uniqueness of `order_number`

Update:

Working code is now:

```
begin
      self.order_number = 5.times.map { [*0..9].sample }.join.to_i
    end while self.class.find_by(order_number: order_number)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The way the code is, it's always at least a 5 digit randomized number or 6 digit.

Plain wrong.

```
1_000_000.
  times.
  map { SecureRandom.random_number(10*10000).to_s.length }.
  uniq
#⇒ [5, 4, 2, 3, 1]
```

`SecureRandom.random_number` does generate the number in the range `0..arg`. You mostly see 5-digits because the probability is higher.

---

I would go with a way simpler approach.

```
def generate_order_number
  order_number = 5.times.map { [*0..9].sample }.join.to_i
  self.class.find_by(order_number: order_number) ? 
    generate_order_number : order_number
end
```

NB! I would suggest making it 9+ digits from the scratch: less probability to hit the existing one and better support for the future when the number of orders will hit a million :)

---

If `order_number` is an actual attribute of the model, we should prefix it with an explicit receiver (`self`):

```
def generate_order_number
  self.order_number = 5.times.map { [*0..9].sample }.join.to_i
  self.class.find_by(order_number: order_number) ? 
    generate_order_number : self.order_number
end
```

Comment: It works but not going into my DB.  This is off topic but why not? When i use either/or `validates :order_number, presence: true
   validates :order_number, uniqueness: true`.. the order wont save.  When i dont use them, the order saves but the order_number doesn't save to the DB.  To note, it is whitelisted in my controller

Comment: Of course, it works. I do not post not working answers. DB issue is mostly like because if `order_number` is _your actual model attribute_, you must prefix assignment with `self.` It’s because setters are not called without an explicit receiver, the internets are full of info about it. I’ll update the answer.

Comment: Lol i know but now the DB is an issue.  But i got it... used the following  `begin
      self.order_number = 5.times.map { [*0..9].sample }.join.to_i
    end while self.class.find_by(order_number: order_number)` ... same as my old code but instead i adopted your random method... THANKS!!!